# Convert Font Awesome pro icons to be hosted locally in React project

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, react-font-awesome

I just found out that we can not use the hosted repo for Font Awesome if we don't pay the yearly subscription for the pro icons.  So I need to host locally.  I am following the instructions here: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/svg-js.  And I have the `fontawesome-pro-6.0.0-web` folder downloaded and added to an `assets` folder in my project.

Now what I am confused about are the next steps, specifically in relation to React.
I currently have code like this:

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faLongArrowDown } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';
import { faPrintSlash } from '@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons';
...
<FontAwesomeIcon
    icon={faLongArrowDown}
    className={'download-arrow semi'}
/>
```

I can't figure out how to convert that to using the local assets.  Can I still use the `FontAwesomeIcon` component?

Comment: Are you trying to just store the fontawesome svgs in a static folder as opposed to using the font awesome package?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is right.  I can't use the globally hosted CDN for the pro icons.  I have to download them and host them locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering, I finally figured this one out.  I was able to keep my `<FontAwesomeIcon ...` code intact and untouched and still use the pro icons hosted locally.  All I did was add these two lines to the top of my `index.js` file:

```js
import './assets/fontawesome-pro-6.0.0-web/js/all.min';
import './assets/fontawesome-pro-6.0.0-web/scss/fontawesome.scss';
```

Comment: But how you still importing the original icon from the same package?
import { faLongArrowDown } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';

Answer (score 0):

you can import the svg files into your component and use them as the source of your images like so:

```
import AddressBook from "./static/addressbook.svg";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img
        src={AddressBook}
        alt="icon"
        style={{ height: "20px", width: "20px" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

here is a working example in a code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-jackson-9ng2jn?file=/src/App.js:23-277

**EDIT:**
if you would prefer your icons to be react components here is an example of how that would look as well:

```
import * as React from "react"

const SvgComponent = (props) => (
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" {...props}>
    <path d="M384 0H96C60.65 0 32 28.65 32 64v384c0 35.35 28.65 64 64 64h288c35.35 0 64-28.65 64-64V64c0-35.35-28.7-64-64-64zM240 128c35.35 0 64 28.65 64 64s-28.65 64-64 64c-35.34 0-64-28.65-64-64s28.7-64 64-64zm96 256H144c-8.8 0-16-7.2-16-16 0-44.2 35.8-80 80-80h64c44.18 0 80 35.82 80 80 0 8.8-7.2 16-16 16zM496 64h-16v96h16c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16V80c0-8.84-7.2-16-16-16zm0 128h-16v96h16c8.8 0 16-7.2 16-16v-64c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm0 128h-16v96h16c8.836 0 16-7.164 16-16v-64c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16z" />
  </svg>
)

export default SvgComponent
```

I have updated the codesandbox above to show how both examples would be used

Comment: I couldn't get this method to work for me.

Comment: did you duplicate what I am doing in my example

Comment: Yeah, but I ended up figuring out an easier way.

Comment: how did you go about it? add it as a solution here it may help others